# GRASS error reading raster map: request for row 1 is outside region

Tags: raster, grass-gis

I'm a rather inexperienced GRASS user, and am trying to use an addon module called r.geomorphon (see http://sil.uc.edu/downloads.html#software). I've managed to get it installed and am trying to run it, but get an error of:

```
ERROR: Reading raster map <decal1@PERMANENT> request for row 1 is outside region
```

and I have no idea what that means. From the Googling that I've done it seems that this error can be caused by some commands when the vector data doesn't overlay the raster data properly - but this routine only uses a single raster DEM file as input. Does anyone have any idea why this might be caused, or do I need to go directly to the author of the addon?

In case it affects things, I'm using a simple arbitrary location, as this DEM was generated by a computer model and therefore only has arbitrary X and Y co-ordinates.

Comment: have you run `g.region rast=decal1` before running the module `g.geomorphon`?

Comment: Oops - I didn't do that. Thank you.